# How to disable horizontal bar

Tags: bootstrap-5, sweetalert2

I am using Sweetalert2 and Bootstrap 5.1.3. I am trying to decorate the Sweetalert like below:

```
        var htmlString = `
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">ID:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">${data.id}</div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">Name:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">${data.name}</div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">Email:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">${data.email}</div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">IsActive?</div> <div class="text-start col-6">${data.active}</div></div>
        `;
```

And my `Swal.fire` block:

```
        Swal.fire({
            titleText: 'You sure to delete this user? ',
            showDenyButton: true,
            //showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            confirmButtonColor: 'green',
            denyButtonText: 'No',
            denyButtonColor: 'gray',
            customClass: {
                actions: 'my-actions',
                confirmButton: 'order-1',
                denyButton: 'order-2 right-gap',
            },
            html: htmlString,
            focusDeny: true,
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                fetch(`${baseURL}/appUsers/${id}`, { method: "delete" });
                var p = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
                p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
                Swal.fire('Deleted Successfully !!', '', 'success');
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
                Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
            }
        })
```

Now the alert has a weird looking horizontal bar like this:

[image]

**Question:** How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a way to style the swal container element from the config, you can add style `overflow-x: hidden` value. Otherwise, you can include a CSS style, after I check the container class name you can use is `.swal2-html-container`

```
.swal2-html-container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

https://codepen.io/david-yappeter/pen/NWwwyQg?editors=1111

// EDIT:
other solution, add `m-0` class after `row`

```
<div class="row m-0"><div class="text-end col-6">ID:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">ID</div></div>
        <div class="row m-0"><div class="text-end col-6">Name:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">NAME</div></div>
        <div class="row m-0"><div class="text-end col-6">Email:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">EMAIL</div></div>
        <div class="row m-0"><div class="text-end col-6">IsActive?</div> <div class="text-start col-6">ACTIVE</div></div>
```

or wrap it with class `container`

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">ID:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">ID</div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">Name:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">NAME</div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">Email:</div> <div class="text-start col-6">EMAIL</div></div>
        <div class="row"><div class="text-end col-6">IsActive?</div> <div class="text-start col-6">ACTIVE</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `First solution` didn't work for me. But `other solution` (m-0) worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. What `m-0` mean by the way? Zero-Margin?

Comment: yeah, margin: 0. doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/